The concept of a single-threaded program doesn't exist to Rust
I'm learning Rust and while doing research on static variables I came across this comment from 2018:

Rust requires everything to be thread-safe (even if you're not using
threads, the concept of a single threaded program doesn't exist to
Rust). Because static variables could be accessed from multiple
threads at once, you have to make static variables thread safe. One
way to do it is to put the value in a Mutex.

So, if I understand this correctly, Rust is assuming the worst-case scenario, that every program compiled is multi-threaded, and even if your program only runs on a single thread then you have to (I'm talking a mutable static):

Wrap the variable in a mutex.
or
Use unsafe { } blocks whenever you access it, right?


Yes. Though there are a few other tools which basically alias to optimised mutexes e.g. LazyLock (for an immutable singleton which has to be initialised at runtime).

Also note that it's extremely difficult to avoid UBs when using raw static mut, even packages like lazy_static hit those issues. So you're really much better off forgetting about static mut unless you literally have no other choice.

Anything wrong with non mutable statics? I mean does what you say apply to them? "Enemy of testability" and so forth?

Non mutable statics must still be thread safe, but by being non mutable most the times they are trivially thread-safe. The most common thing is having to use LazyLock instead of (the bit faster) LazyCell.

You're correct that Rust assumes static variables may be accessed multiple threads, but threads aren't the only motivation for limitations on static mut. For example, prior to Rust edition 2024, it was possible to write &STATIC_VAR in safe code, which produces a 'static reference that is unsound to hold past future mutation, even on the same thread. Luckily, the options for implementing mutable global variables are not as limited as you describe. Here are some additional options:

If applicable (variables that are initialized once and then immutable), use LazyLock<T> or OnceLock<T>, depending on where you want to write the initialization function.
Optimize Mutex<T> and RwLock<T> to atomic_refcell::AtomicRefCell<T>, for performance. Concurrent access would panic instead of blocking, but you don't need to worry about that. You still need to worry about re-entrant access, though. (the fact that Mutex<T> is optimized for the uncontended case is duly noted)
Use thread_local! with Cell<T> or RefCell<T>, depending if you need a reference, which may be more ergonomic.
If possible, change static mut variables into local variables of main. Pass mutable references wherever they are needed.
If applicable (bool, integers, pointers), optimize Mutex<T> to AtomicT with Ordering::Relaxed.
If applicable (web development), compile for wasm32 (WebAssembly) in non-atomic mode, which is currently the default. The Mutex<T> and RwLock<T> implmentations get replaced with this and this that barely do any work.
If applicable (embedded systems), find a Mutex for your architecture, such as this general embedded Mutex using the notion of an architecture-specific 'critical section.'

Also, it's worth noting that unsafe accesses to static mut are not immune from soundness issues in a "single-threaded" context. You still need to manually enforce lifetimes, prevent unsound re-entrant execution, and take into account unexpected concurrency due to signal handlers (OS) or interrupt handlers (embedded).

Unfortunately none of these options are available on a bare metal embedded target without atomic support... Well, except (3), which is not possible or feasible in many cases. it. And it is a real pain in the.. everywhere..

For single-threaded embedded, you could copy and adapt the wasm32 non-atomic Mutex implementation or use an existing library that does this. Will update answer!

@EugeneSh. Bare metal targets have interrupts, which are like threads.

@ChayimFriedman Similarly, as you probably already know, larger OS's have signal handlers and, to handle them, there may be hidden threads. AFAIK none of my options would lead to UB if signals or interrupts were accidentally triggered. I updated the warning about static mut at the end of my answer.

@ChayimFriedman Yes, and no... You usually don't want an interrupt handler to suspend on mutex. In general I prefer to not let interrupts to even try to use shared resources, so the existing sync mechanisms aren't really suitable. In addition the whole interrupt handler on some configs (without nested interrupts) can be considered a critical section. I have some makeshift solutions, such as passing around tokens indicating interrupt/non-interrupt context, but I wish there was more "official" support.
